# rvm and gem ssl issue

Tags: rubygems, openssl, rvm

I'm in a bit of a mess with an rvm install on an Ubuntu 22.04 VM. The position I'm currently in is

- I have succesfully installed the latest rvm (stable)
- I used rvm to install the latest openssl (`rvm pkg install openssl`)
- I have installed ruby 3.1.0 successfully
- **But** when I try and install any gem I get an error: at the heart of the error is the following:

> `gem SSL_connect returned=1 errorno=0 peeraddr=151.101.1.227:443 state = error:wrong version number (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz`)

I started with a standard curl rvm install (`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`) - to cut a long story short it failed (ruby 3.0) with an openSSL error. I managed to cure it by installing `openSSL 1.1.1.q`, which enabled me to install ruby 3.0. But at this point I couldn't get `gem` to find any OpenSSL libraries. After a couple of hours trying various options with no joy, I uninstalled `openSSL 1.1.1q`, and did `rvm implode` to remove rvm, so I could start again with a clean sheet.

This time when I installed the stock rvm from curl (`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`) it succeeded with no problems. I then used rvm into instal openSSL (`rvm pkg install openSSL`), followed by ruby 3.1 (`rvm install ruby-3.1.0`). This is all good, but I now have the gem issue above.

The gem path resolves to the gem within ruby-3.1.0 under rvm.

Anyone got any thoughts on how to resolve - I'm not sure what the next step should be to debug and resolve.

Thanks :-)